# Interpreting the given seasonal plot and checking the presence of seasonality

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality

Would there be any seasonality to be interpreted in this plot? I see that February and September may show seasonality but am unsure the best way to interpret this. Link to another question that may provided additional context: [Explaining ARIMA forecasts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598243/explaining-arima-forecasts)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try plotting the averaged seasonality with some measure of spread or a confidence bound. That might be more instructive than this (though this is a great start).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to include [a link to your previous question on this time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/598243/1352). Given the likely impact of an intervention (specifically, the COVID pandemic, and people's response of staying home, and burglars' likely response to *that* of not breaking and entering so much), I would be very careful about looking for seasonality on the original data. If at all, regress your data on a dummy variable that is 1 since the pandemic starts, then assess seasonality on residuals from that regression.

Your seasonal plot does not really show a lot of signal. Beware of squinting at such plots and convincing yourself that there *is something there*. Humans are amazingly good at seeing patterns where none exist. [This](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3107/1352) is what a *clear* seasonal signal looks like.

Per above, I would recommend running `auto.arima` with external regressors. It is quite good in applying statistical tests to decide whether or not to include seasonality.

Comment: Thanks you again for another insightful answer @stephankolassa. I will have to do a bit more discovery on how to regress my data on a dummy variable like you mentioned. I'm still new to R so some flows are still foreign to me!

Comment: You can feed a Boolean time series into the `xreg` parameter of `auto.arima()`.